# Site-to-Site IPsec VPN Tunnel - Certain Traffic Doesn't Work

Tags: cisco, vpn, ipsec, tunnel

I've been having some strange issues with some site-to-site IPsec tunnels using ESP and pre-shared keys that I've been working on for the past two weeks with no success. The tunnel has no problem coming up, but certain traffic just doesn't want to pass over the link and I cannot for the life of me figure out why. We have 12 tunnels to remote locations, all configured identically and just about all with identical hardware (all Cisco 867VAE or 861 routers except for two of the sites), but these problems are only affecting 4 of the tunnels.

I have a mountain of details and a list of all the different types of things that do and don't work over the tunnel, but to keep it simple let's just stick with this particular one: I'm unable to send pings from the main office (where our Cisco ASA 5512-X is) to the remote location (where the router is; two of these locations are Cisco 867VAE routers, one is an old Cisco 2811 router, and one is a TP-Link TD-W8960N) over the VPN tunnel. However, pings from the remote location to the main office over the VPN tunnel work just fine. Any idea what might cause this behavior?

For reference there are four different ISPs involved, so I'm assuming it's not an issue with one particular ISP, but just in case it's relevant: We have three bonded T1's at our main office through Time Warner, while at the remote locations we have two with T1's (one through AT&T and one through Level 3) and two with DSL through CenturyLink. In case it matters none of our tunnels are very heavily used at all (usually just supporting two or three computers and a couple IP phones), so it definitely shouldn't be network congestion causing this somehow.

I've already triple-checked my configuration, rebooted everything, wiped out the configuration and re-added it, tried a different model Cisco router at the location with the 2811, and just for the heck of it I played with a variety of MTU and MSS values on both the ASA and remote router, but no difference. I can provide additional details on traffic that works and doesn't work as well as specific configuration details or show command output if needed.

Comment: It sounds like the remote site which can't respond to ping, but which can initiate a successful ping, are blocking ICMP echo requests, either on the router or the host to which you are sending ping. This question is really too broad to answer without details like a drawing and configurations. The ISP will be oblivious about what is traveling in a VPN tunnel.

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. You could improve your question by editing it to add more details. You may find our [Question Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/33) helpful when editing your question. For example:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was my fault, I didn't realize that the order of the NAT statements in the ASA actually made any difference, I had a bunch of static NAT entries for servers (and my own computer) and I just needed to make sure that the double NAT statement that keeps traffic intended to be tunneled from being NAT'ed appears above all my static NAT entries so that it occurs first.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up, looking for an answer, forever.